# How to pass value from VBScript to MSBuild property?

Tags: vbscript, msbuild

I have a vbscript that returns the product version of my executable.

**GetProductVersion.vbs**

```
Option Explicit 
Dim aFileFullPath, aDetail, Result
aFileFullPath = "PATH_TO_MY_EXE_FILE"
aDetail = "Product Version"
Result=fGetFileDetail(aFileFullPath, aDetail)
wscript.echo Result

Function fGetFileDetail(aFileFullPath, aDetail)
    Dim pvShell, pvFileSystemObject, pvFolderName, pvFileName, pvFolder, pvFile, i
    Set pvFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If pvFileSystemObject.FileExists(aFileFullPath) Then
         pvFolderName = pvFileSystemObject.GetFile(aFileFullPath).ParentFolder
         pvFileName = pvFileSystemObject.GetFile(aFileFullPath).Name

         Set pvShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
         Set pvFolder = pvShell.Namespace(pvFolderName)
         Set pvFile = pvFolder.ParseName(pvFileName)

         fGetFileDetail = "Detail not detected"

         For i = 0 To 399
              If uCase(pvFolder.GetDetailsOf(pvFolder.Items, i)) = uCase(aDetail) Then
                   fGetFileDetail = pvFolder.GetDetailsOf(pvFile, i)
              End If
         Next
    Else
         fGetFileDetail = "File not found"
    End If
End Function
```

If I run this script it will show me the correct result - 5.1.0.35 in my case, so the script itself works fine. But I want to run this script in MSBuild and set value that it will return to MSBuild property.

In other words, I have a property with default value defined in my Msbuild proj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <ProdVersion>5.1.0.0</ProdVersion>
............
</PropertyGroup>
```

But later its value (5.1.0.0) should be replaced with result of **GetProductVersion.vbs** execution:

I know, that I can run vbs smth like this:

```
<Target Name="SetProductVersion">
     <Exec Command="&quot;$(PathToVbScripts)\GetProductVersion.vbs&quot;" />
....
```

But how can I set *ProdVersion* property to the value that GetProductVersion.vbs will return?

Comment: If you post the implementation in fGetFileDetail, we can show you how to port your code to MsBuild :)

Comment: @Nick, fGetFileDetail(aFileFullPath, aDetail) returns some value and I set it to Result variable (see the 5-th line). I only need to pass Result value to MSBuild, so I don't understand why you ask me to post fGetFileDetail implementaion... In any case, I've just added it for you.